# How to add a link in a Lightbox2 image caption

Tags: html, lightbox2

Using the script Lightbox2
I would like to place a link (`<a>` tag) in the description of the image.

For example:

I would replace "Click the right half of the image to move foward." with 
 [*Visit My site!*](http://www.my0000site.com)

Watch this [Image](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2remzjk.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a link in the caption by simply adding the anchor tag in the data-title attribute. For example:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-lightbox="example" data-title="Optional <a href='http://google.com'>caption</a>.">My image link</a>
```

The ability to add anchor tags directly in the data-title attribute without having to encode them first was added in version 2.7.2 on 2015-06-16. Make sure to upgrade if you're using an older version, as this option won't work in older versions of the plugin:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: How can i encode the link into the `data-title` attribute. I'm using Twig templates

Comment: very nice solution. what if I want to add an onClick event in that link, say onClick='alert(my name here)' ?